# Difference between writing stuff directly into URDF vs. into <gazebo reference=""> tags?

Tags: kinect, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I'm wondering what the  tag actually does? Is there a difference between writing stuff directly into a URDF file and writing it into a  tag?

E.g. I can set mue for a link as follows:

```
 <contact_coefficient mu="100000"  resitution="0"  k_p="0"  k_d="100" />
```

But also via the tag

```
 <gazebo reference="link">
  <mu1>1e10</mu1>
  <mu2>1e10</mu2>
 </gazebo>
```

What's the difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22230/difference-between-writing-stuff-directly-into-urdf-vs.-into-%3Cgazebo-reference=%22%22%3E-tags?/) by [steradiant](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8551/steradiant/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As far as I know...
A gazebo reference tag tells your ROS URDF file what properties a link should have in gazebo. It defines the behavior of a link when it is spawned within the gazebo environment ONLY. What you put within a gazebo reference tag does not affect how your robot behaves for instance in RVIZ.
Case in point... See below

```
  
  
  
  
  
  0.0000001
  0.00001
  Gazebo/Black
```

This snippet reference says for the front_left_wheel link within the gazebo environment... Set values to blablabla... That link would then go on to behave with the set parameters WITHIN GAZEBO only.

---

Originally posted by [afroRoboticist](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8862/afroroboticist/) with karma: 48 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0